# Array Data Calculation

Tags: php, mysql, sql, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have met problem dealing with multidimensional array. Below are the code to store all the data query from mysql to array. May I know is there any idea how to calculate how many different module name in the multidimensional array and break the status into 2 column which are late and present? The SQL query get the data from a complex table which store all ModuleName and different status. I need to categories them and show in a table. So basically I need to check how many module in the array and how many late or present for the module.

```
while($array = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        $list[] = array(
                        "ModuleName"=>$array['ModuleName'],
                        "status"    =>$array['Status']
            ); 
    }
```

[image: Sample of the SQL query]

This is the sample of expected result

[image: Sample Expected Result]

Comment: `$counts[$array['Status']]++`?

Comment: So, you want the output to be a single row with 3 columns (module count, late, present)? Can you share the SQL to retrieve the data and the underlying data structure? I'm guessing this can probably be easily performed in your SQL query.

Comment: @MarcB This don't work as I need according to the Module Name to get how many late and how many present.

Comment: so `$counts[$array['ModuleName']][$array['Status']]++`...

Comment: @MarcB Not working bro ~ The status is different ~ How u gonna count if the array store different of value? It will just get the same row I get from SQL

Comment: if you have CE00300-1/present, CEe00300-1/late, CE003001-1/foo, then you'll get 3 different elements in the $count array, one for each of those 3 status, and the value of that key pair will be how many times present/late/foo showed up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated to group by ModuleName**

```
SELECT ModuleName
      ,COUNT(*) AS module_count
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status != 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as late_count
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status  = 'Present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as present_count
  FROM ( your original query )
 GROUP BY ModuleName
```

Just replace "your original query" with the SQL you used to retrieve the data in the array.

**Original**

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS module_count
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status != 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as late_count
      ,SUM(CASE WHEN Status  = 'present' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as present_count
  FROM ( your original query )
```

Comment: great to c this. Anyway, i have used this sql query to pull the data. Cause this database design is quite a mess. SO lastly i joined some of the table to get all the info.

SELECT * , a.AttendanceID AS id
FROM classes AS c, attendances AS a, incharges AS i
WHERE a.StudentID =  "TP000001"
AND a.ClassID = c.ClassID
AND c.InchargeID = i.InchargeID
LIMIT 0 , 30

Comment: Thanks so much. It help a lot. Is there any way to filter the module and filter the status at the same time? =D If I didn't get the wrong information, currently the sql is filter the status from the same module, am i correct?

Comment: Not quite sure what you're asking for. It would help a lot if you would 1) show sample data, 2) show expected results, 3) show your current SQL.

Comment: I would like to know the ModuleName should replace with the picture I show above "ModuleName" right? the module_count, late_count and present_count are the variable to store the number of module, number of late and number of present? The question is the sql query i show in earlier comment, i pull all the module and attendance related to the student. So the data might appear to have different of module name and different of status.